# Plot horizontal bars using seaborn.objects interface (v0.12)

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, seaborn-0.12.x

In the original API, [`barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) provided an `orient` parameter to swap bar orientation:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 5)), columns=[*"abcde"])
#    a  b  c  d  e
# 0  8  6  5  2  3
# 1  0  0  0  1  8
# 2  6  9  5  6  9

sns.barplot(data=df, orient="h")
```

[image]

In the `objects` API, it seems we should now [`add`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Plot.add.html#seaborn.objects.Plot.add) the orientation to the mark layer, but I'm not sure how:

```py
import seaborn.objects as so

so.Plot(data=df).add(so.Bar(), so.Agg(), orient="h")
# ValueError: No grouping variables are present in dataframe
```

What is the idiomatic way to change bar orientation with the new `objects` API?

Comment: Per the documentation **The bars are oriented depending on the x/y variable types and the orient parameter** https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Bar.html For horizontal, put the categorical variable on the y-axis. I’m not sure if there’s an issue with the documentation, since `orient` isn’t used in the examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw horizontal bars with the objects interface and `add` does have an `orient` parameter (although it accepts `x`/`y` rather than `v`/`h` as the former generalize better over all kinds of marks).

But what is not currently supported here is plotting ["wide form"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html) data.

The problem with wide-form data is that different kinds of plots will use the dimensions of the dataset differently. With the function interface, each function kind can specify the mapping (e.g. `barplot` maps columns to `x` (or `y` for horizontal bars), while `lineplot` maps the index to `x`.

I don't know whether the objects interface will support this at some point, but it does not currently. You'll need to convert your dataframe to long-form and explicitly assign x/y.

Comment: I think I'm finally wrapping my head around the new `x`/`y`/`orient`. The old `orient` did some magic on the axes/aggregation depending on the data and function, whereas the new `orient` strictly refers to aggregation orientation (and never swaps axes).

Comment: After messing around with this a bit, it seems this even allows "weird" stuff that wasn't previously supported, like aggregating the categorical axis: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJKn7.png

Comment: Again, there's no magic here with `orient`. The "magic" such as it exists is all in assigning implicit variables for wide-form data.

Comment: Yes, generally speaking the objects interface is more likely to let you do weird things that don't necessarily make sense so that it does not prevent you from doing weird things that do.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, to replicate the original horizontal [`barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) behavior for wide-form data:

```
# old interface
sns.barplot(data=df, orient="h")
```

We now need to [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) into long-form and explicitly swap `x`/`y`:

```
# new interface
so.Plot(
    data=df.melt(), # convert to long-form
    x="value",      # set x as numeric
    y="variable",   # set y as categorical
).add(
    so.Bar(),
    so.Agg(),
)
```

[image]